# Windows Phone 8 APP Deployment with Capabilities?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, nfc

I have an App that has a Requirement of NFC but I want to install this app on any Windows Phone 8 devices. therefore, How do i manage to do that or is there any other requirement or capability I must Tick or Untick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

(1) Open your WMAppManifest.xml and add the capability ID_CAP_PROXIMITY.

[image: ID_CAP_PROXIMITY]

(2) If NFC is a requirement, you can limit your application to Windows Phone device with NFC capability. edit Properties -> WMAppManifest.xml file and check ID_REQ_NFC in Requirements tab.

[image: NFC Requirement]

(3) Test if NFC is available

```
if (ProximityDevice.GetDefault() != null)
   MessageBox.Show("NFC present");
 else
   MessageBox.Show("Your phone has no NFC or NFC is disabled");
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is there any possibility if i could turn the requirement off if NFC is not available? or something similar cause i wanna get the app to the phone whether NFC is available or now

Comment: Don't follow the 2nd step & you are good to go. If you don't want to specify hardware requirement then don't, & the 3rd step will let you know weather NFC is present or not or disabled in the user's wp device.